# How do I append an element with form data? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, client-side

```
 <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
          return false;
        $('table').append(
            `<tr>
              <td>$('#first').val();</td>
              <td>$('#last').val();</td>
             <td>$('#email').val();</td>
              <td>$('#phone').val();</td>
             </tr>`);
          });
   });
 </script>
```

The console is not showing any errors, but when I click the submit button, nothing happens.
The Jquery file loaded is Google's hosted library. Using Chrome.

Comment: concatenate your variables and then terminate your strings.

Comment: You are calling return before `$('table').append(...`.  I ran your code without it and it worked.

Comment: I moved the return false; to the end of the block. But now it doesn't seem to be working...it is submitting the form as usual (but I do see the append happening.)

Answer (score 4):

When you `return false`, the code after this is ignored, use `e.preventDefault()` to avoid the page reload, and at the time of displaying, you need to concatenate your strings and your variables (which in this case is `$(input).val()`) to display the correct value, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('table').append("<tr><td>"+$('#first').val()+"</td><td>"
                            +$('#last').val()+"</td><td>"
                            +$('#email').val()+"</td><td>"
                            +$('#phone').val()+"</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

Comment: So I've updated it this way, however, the form keeps submitting as usual now that I have moved the return false; and added that e.preventDefault();